# Spring Boot - MySQL to Postgres migration

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with mysql database. I'm planning to migrate this to postgres database. So, do I need to change anything in the entity classes(like datatypes) and JPA repositories?

Comment: This depends how your entites look like.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this myself so I cannot speak from experience. The abstraction layer of JPA should be able to do this depending on how you used and extended the platform.

If you only used JPA (and additional Spring) annotations in your classes and kept your custom queries to JPQL then you should be good to go.

If you extended your code with Native Queries or if you extended the types to support MySQL only types, you might need to make changes. But again this depends on which libraries you used. One of the more common custom types such as JSON in hibernate would be supported in both if you used https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types.

So there is no definitive answer, it really depends on your code-base.